# Network Analysis Problems with SystemModeler

Tags: graphs-and-networks, system-modeler

Is it possible to analyse network problems like shortest path, minimum spanning tree, maximum flow, travelling salesman etc. with SystemModeler? If so where cm I find tutorials and examples?

Comment: I never used SystemModeler, but I had the impression that it is specifically for problems that can be formulated as a set of ordinary differential equations (or differential-algebraic equations), with time as a variable.  I don't think it is designed for combinatorial problems.

Comment: Maybe you are misled by the fact that a Modelica model can be graphically represented as a set of connected blocks.  It looks like a network.  That doesn't mean it has anything to do with analysing graphs.

Comment: **Wolfram SystemModeler** mainly depends on the **Modelica** language to model and simulation. In addtion, there is a package called **WSMLink** that let the user analysis the Modelica model in *Mathematica* notebook. About the book, I have read *"the Introduction to physical modeling with modelica"* written by Michael Tiller. There is also a [webbook](http://book.xogeny.com/) called *Modelica by Example*, which is also a portion of **SystemModeler Documentation**.

Answer (score 2):

A summary of good pointers provided in comments:

**Szabolcs** mentioned that "I never used SystemModeler, but I had the impression that it is **specifically for problems that can be formulated as a set of ordinary differential equations** (or differential-algebraic equations), with time as a variable. I don't think it is designed for combinatorial problems. Maybe you are misled by the fact that a *Modelica* model can be graphically represented as a set of connected blocks. **It looks like a network. That doesn't mean it has anything to do with analysing graphs**."

**Shutao** also added that "Wolfram SystemModeler mainly depends on the Modelica language to model and simulation. In addition, there is a package called `` WSMLink` `` that lets the user analyze the Modelica model in a *Mathematica* notebook. About the book, I have read the ["Introduction to physical modeling with Modelica"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0792373677) written by Michael Tiller. There is also a web-book called [*Modelica by Example*](http://book.xogeny.com/) by the same author, which is a portion of the [*SystemModeler* Documentation](https://www.modelica.org/publications)."